# exe stringtable in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, string-table

How do i read/set the exe's string table in C#? I don't mean resource file. I mean take any exe, open it in visual studios, right click and select "Add Resource" then select string table which is a uint16 key and string value.

How do i access that in C#?

Comment: You want to edit .NET .RESX Resources, or WIN32 .RC resources? embedded in an .exe/dll ?

Answer (score 0):

Well... This is easy to answer... Harder to implement though.

What you need to do is:

1. Create a [Visual Studio Extension](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd885119.aspx).
2. Familiarize yourself with the file format, [Portable Executable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Executable).
3. Learn how to inject data into said [Portable Executable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Executable).
4. Write code to implement the above.

On the other hand, which type of executable are we talking about?
There a many different kinds and if you mean ANY kind then you're going to have fun for a long, long time.